# Selective syncing of MySQL database with SQLite

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to develop an Android app that provides information on a chosen topic. All the information is stored on a MySQL database with one table for each topic. What I want to achieve is that when the user chooses a topic, the corresponding table should be downloaded to SQLite so that it can be used offline. Also, any changes to that particular table in the MySQL should be in synced with the SQLite db automatically when the phone connects to Internet the next time.

I have understood how to achieve the connection using PHP and HTTP requests. What I wanna know what is the best logic to sync any entries in a particular table in MuSQL database to the one in SQLite. I read about using various sync services but I don't understand how to use them. All my tables have exactly the same schema so is there an efficient way to achieve the sync ?

I have a decent knowledge in SQL but I'm kinda new to Android.

Comment: Well if you are only sending data from the phone why don't you save in SQLite first. That way you always have the info offline and the only place you would need to update it is in the MySQL database when you gain connection. Depending on how large these tables are, you can run a query that compares the amount of records. If there is a mismatch, find the id of the records that aren't in MySQL and send that over from the SQLite database. Once again, I don't know how efficient this is. You could look into AWS services. Cognito has a data sync feature that may be able to help you. Just a though.

Comment: Thank you @drew , I'll certainly look into the services you mentioned. But yeah, I want all the information stored on the MySQL database as I mentioned. Only the table that is required needs to be downloaded onto the phone. And the size of each table might get too large to compare the IDs of each record to find what records are not there in the local database. I might be underestimating the comparison speed though.

Comment: @Akhil Curious, why you need one table per topic assuming that the information is similarly structured for each topic. Do you mean one row per topic?